# Fundamental group - space of copies of circle $S_1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fundamental-groups

For $n>1$ an integer, let $W_n$ be the space formed by taking $n$ copies of the circle $S_1$ and identifying all the $n$ base points to form a new base point, called $w_0$.
What is $\pi_{1}$($W_n , w_0 $ )?

The fundamental group is the set of all homotopy classes of loops with base point $w_0$ forms the fundamental group of $W_n$ at the point $w_0$

I know the fundamental group of the circle is $\mathbb{Z}$, the set of integers

So would it be $n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Have you heard of the [free product of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product)?

Comment: Note that the notion $nZ$ does not really make sense as a group on its own right but rather as the subgroup of $Z$ which is generated by $n$. As this subgroup it isomorphic to $Z$, though.

Comment: @StefanHamcke ok thanks. so it has the same FG as the circle?

Comment: @k.stm no I havnt. So, in this case, what would the 'words' be?

Comment: @StefanHamcke Of course $n\Bbb Z$ makes sense as a group in its own right. You said yourself that it is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, and every subgroup of any given group is indeed a group in its own right.

Comment: @AlexG. What I meant was that you would only write the group as $n\Bbb Z$ when you want to emphasize that it is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$. When talking about the fundamental group of a space, you would rather call it $\Bbb Z$ instead of $n\Bbb Z$ (unless it is the fundamental group of a space $A$ with a map $f:A\to X$ and this induces an embedding of $\pi_1(A)$ as $n\Bbb Z$ into $\pi_1(X)=\Bbb Z$).

Comment: @StefanHamcke Of course we would. However if someone wrote $\pi_1(S^1) = n\Bbb Z$ they would be just as correct as someone who wrote $\pi_1(S^1) = \Bbb Z$. The former is strange notation, but mathematically there is no difference at all. $n\Bbb Z$ is a perfectly good group on its own.

Comment: @AlexG. Writing the $\pi_1$ as $n\Bbb Z$ would be correct. I still think that the $n$ should somehow be justified, though. For example, when there is a covering map $p:X\to Y$ with $\pi_1(Y)=\Bbb Z$ and you have figured out that $p_*(\pi_1(X)) = n\Bbb Z$, then I'd say it makes sense to write $\pi_1(X)$ as $n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke What you're writing is opinion, not mathematics. My original criticism was of your statement "the notion $n\Bbb Z$ does not really make sense as a group on its own right" which is mathematically incorrect.

Comment: @AlexG. You are right, I should have formulated my original comment in a different way, so that the OP does not get the idea that "$n\Bbb Z$ is not a group". My intention with that comment was to express my opinion that when you write $\pi_1(X)=n\Bbb Z$, you should explain where the $n$ is coming from.

Answer (score 4):

You maybe want to look at [Van Kampen Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem), and for example, Hatcher Chapter 1, Example 1.21, in which it is shown that $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, where $*$ denotes [free products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product), and $A\vee B$ denotes $A\amalg B /{\sim}$, with $\sim$ defined by the identification of $a_0, b_0$ for pointed spaces $A,B$, with points $a_0$, $b_0$.

Try to generalise the above to the wedge sum of $n$ circles.

Comment: I think what's looked over a lot is that Van Kampen gives isomorphism with amalgamated free product. For the open sets U,V it is canonical to use the copies of $S^1$ which will intersect at the wedge point. Therefore, for induction case where $n = 2$ we have $\pi_1(S^1_a \vee S^1_b) \cong \mathbb{Z} *_{\{0\}} \mathbb{Z}$. However since the inclusion maps of the image for loops in the intersection is trivial we get the group presentation $\langle a,b | - \rangle = F(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can understand $W_n$ as a CW-complex, so you have one $0$-cell $e^0_1$ and $n$ copies of $1$-cells $e^1_i$ ($i=1,\dots, n$) and any $m$-cell with $m>1$, so it means that if you want the fundamental group, you have $n$ diferent generators (one for each $1$-cell) and you don't have any restriction, so it means that you obtain that the fundamental group is $\pi_1(W_n)=\ast_{i=0}^n\mathbb{Z}e^1_i\cong \ast_{i=0}^n\mathbb{Z} \cong F[n]$ (where $F[n]$ is the amalgamated group of $n$ generators). In conclusion, $\pi_1(W_n)\cong \langle a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \rangle$

Comment: It's not really clear what your reasoning here... The CW-complex structure is barely relevant, whereas van Kampen's theorem (which you don't mention) is crucial.

Comment: Well, as I was taught how to get the fundamental group of an easy CW-complex with $n$-cells of order $n<3$ first you draw it and give directions in the way you want (remembering that all the elements that represent the same must have the same direction), then you make a maximal tree such that it doesn't have cycles of any size (it means, a spanning tree). Then you count the rest of 1-cells you have (they will be your generators for the group) and finally you see the restrictions that are the 2-cells you have that is the word generated  by rounding it with the word.

Comment: For example, if we consider this case, you can use the 0-cell $w_0$ as the origin of your spanning tree. As you don't have to reach any other 0-cell, your tree is full. Then you count the number of 1-cells you have, that are $n$. And finally you count the restrictions that in this case doesn't exist, so your fundamental group is the finitely generated group of $n$ generators without any restriction.

Comment: It may be a very childish way to do it, but is valid, I think.

Comment: It's not "childish", but it's obfuscating the main result... You're jumping through hoops when the tool needed to prove the result you're using (van Kampen's theorem) is already more simple in its application...